# JavaFX TextField text validation

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, keyevent

I have a `listener` applied to my field:

```
nameTextField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, fieldChangeListener(50));
```

Event handler:

```
private EventHandler<KeyEvent> fieldChangeListener(final Integer max_Lengh) {
        return new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                TextField field = (TextField) event.getSource();
                String text = field.getText();
                // I need here something like:
                if(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                // do special part for ENTER KEY
                }
            }
         }
}
```

Problem is `KeyEvent event` is from `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent` and `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` from `com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent`. I don't know how can I determine if ENTER key triggered `KEY_TYPED` event.

Comment: What do you want to achieve at the end?

Comment: Basically, I want to control user input. That's why I'm using `key_typed`, but problem is that I don't want certain code to be executed when ENTER key is pressed. In case of ENTER I don't want it to go through input validation, but rather through minor full word check.

Comment: Don't use key listeners to validate input in a text field. Use a `TextFormatter` if you want to restrict or manipulate user input, and use an `onAction` handler if you want to validate when the user presses Enter (or commits in another way).

Comment: Yes, @James_D is right, I did not know if it is a "validation" or a "prevention" use case. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do input validation when the text is changing, you could use a listener on the `textProperty` of the `TextField`:

```
textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
    System.out.println("Input Validation"));
```

To detect when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, you can use the `onActionProperty`

```
textField.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Enter pressed: Word Check"));
```

---

If you want to prevent the user to input characters that fails the validation logic, then rather than listening to the `textProperty˙`, you can use a `TextFormatter` (this `TextField` only accept integers):

```
textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(change ->
         (change.getControlNewText().matches("([1-9][0-9]*)?")) ? change : null));
```

Comment: I'm using `KEY_TYPED` event

Comment: Okay, I don't really understand the reason behind, but I updated the answer based on your requirements, that may suit better to your needs.

Comment: I was thinking of that before, but with it it's not possible to control user input, preventing him from typing wrong characters. I'm currently looking into possibility of switching to `KEY_PRESSED`. First minus that I came across, how to check result if `BACKSPACE` is being used? How can you determine the length of `BACKSPACE` if user selected part of the word and deleted it?

Comment: It was not clear if you want to validate: the user types and you calculate if the typed string is valid, or you want to prevent the user to type invalid characters. In the latter case a `TextFormatter` can be used. Updated the answer.

Comment: What does `? change : null` means?

Comment: @k_plan: It is the [ternary operator](https://www.javatpoint.com/ternary-operator-in-java) in Java, which is the short for for `if (condition) then change else null`.